# get values of certain key in multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $arr which looks like this when I print_r($arr):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 8
            [name] => name0
            [slug] => slug0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 7
            [name] => name1
            [slug] => slug1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 6
            [name] => name2
            [slug] => slug2
        )

)
```

now, I want to be able to get all the values of [name] in an array so later I can use this array to filter some data.
So the output I'm looking for is something like:

```
array(0 => 'name0', 1 => 'name1', 2 => 'name2', 3 => 'name3');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (**Note:** This syntax requires PHP 5.3+)

```
$names = array_map(function($a){ return $a->name; }, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

First: `$array = (array) $arr;`.

Then:

```
foreach($array as $a) {
    $data[] = $a['name'];
}
```

`$data` should contain array you are looking for (didn't try code but it should be ok).